# iTunes Match uploading slowness with eventual error -9810

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

After several weeks now and still in dialogue with Apple third tier support still haven't resolved an upload problem, can anyone help?

I have around 12,500 tracks out of which iTunes Match found purchases, matched and uploaded a significant number leaving me with around 3000 tracks in 'uploading' status. Then the whole system slowed down. At the present rate it will take over twelve months to upload the remaining tracks. iTunes gets to around 10 uploads (on a good day) and then seems to just stop uploading but leaving iTunes itself unaffected - not crashed. On some occasions but not all I get an error message -9810 which Apple Support have no note for.

Any one cured this one before?

Answer (score 1):

According to a the [Apple Discussion Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3581412?start=0&tstart=0), it's a sign on authentication error (SSL). You should try to sign out, sign on elsewhere and sign back on your iMac. When you do sign out, some flags on the Apple Servers are reset or restored, so you could sign on with the proper speed and permissions again.

Or you could change from WiFi to Ethernet or vice versa, this is also mentionned as a solution.

The article mentions more solutions, so I suggest you take a look at the article if above information doesn't help you out.